# How to assign number to datagridview textboxcolumn on click event?

Tags: c#, datagridview

The `gridview` is databound using(`sqlcommand`, `datatable`).and first column is empty text box.

How can i give number to text box on `cell_click` event ?

Means when i click on row that row(first column) must assign number (start from number 1) to text column cell

following table is my gridview

[image: loaded gridview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handel the event `dataGridView1` of your `datagridView` like :

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column1"].Value = n.ToString ();
            n++;
        }
```

and declare a variable `n` as `int` in the top of your form like :

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int n = 1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Comment: Glad to hear thet & Happy to help

Comment: another question is how to take that column value to variable for comparing purpose

Comment: string value=(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["number"].Value).ToString();   i tried this but not working

Comment: "number" is the name of your column ?

Comment: yes, and when second time i click that row , row data must be clear(only text box value)

Comment: I did not understand exactly what you trying to do